# Get list of modules called at order success page - M2

Tags: magento2, orders, cart, order-success-page

**Place order is working good but after place order page redirect to cart page.**

I have put log in **success.phtml** file and found that **success.phtml file is called.**

But I don't know why it's redirect to empty cart page. This issue is occurring some random time.

So i want to know the list of modules called at success page, maybe some custom module creating issue with session.

**Can anyone help me to get list of modules called at success page?**

**File:** vendor\magento\module-checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success.php

There is some issue with session : **if (!$this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator::class)->isValid())**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface as HttpGetActionInterface;

/**
 * Onepage checkout success controller class
 */
class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * Order success action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $session = $this->getOnepage()->getCheckout();
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/cart_redirect.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info("Reached Controller/Onepage/Success.php to redirect on cart. Last placed OrderId: ".$session->getLastOrderId());

        if (!$this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator::class)->isValid()) {
            $logger->info("Before Redirect from Controller/Onepage/Success.php to redirect on cart. Last placed OrderId: ".$session->getLastOrderId());
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
        $session->clearQuote();
        //@todo: Refactor it to match CQRS
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action',
            [
                'order_ids' => [$session->getLastOrderId()],
                'order' => $session->getLastRealOrder()
            ]
        );
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you check the log file? and in which payment method order you face this issues?

Comment: Not getting any help from log, paypal express and authorized.net

Comment: @JimitBhavsar Did u find any solution for this issue? I am facing same issue even with Check money order payment method as well. Magento version is: Enterprise 2.3.5-p2

Comment: It' redis cache issue and we have remove it